# running servlet from the jsp-page

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have the index.jsp page:

```
</head>
<body>
     <form action="HelloWorldServlet" method="post">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="load list" />
     </form>
</body>
</head>
```

where i want to run my HelloWorldServlet by clicking the "load list"-button.

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("Hello, World!");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

but instead of "Hello, World!" message, it try to load `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorldServlet` page.. what's the point?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD 
  Web Application 2.3//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd'>
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what URL is your servlet mapped to?

Comment: **<url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>**

Comment: Please include the content of your web.xml in the question.

Comment: i don't want to go on another url, i just want my servlet to add "Hello, world!" to a current page

Comment: I have no idea what you're concretely asking, so here's just a suggestion to go through some basic servlet tutorials: put your mouse above the `[servlets]` tag which you've put on the question yourself until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link :) Happy developing! By the way, assure that you're reading up to date tutorials/resources, Servlet 2.3 is almost a decade old already, we're currently at Servlet 3.0.

Comment: I'm asking how to add two words (Hello, world) to the page index.jsp by clicking the button on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your servlet is mapped to `/hello`, then your `<form>` should be posting to the same URL.

```
<form action="hello" method="post">
```

Comment: i see, but is there a way to add "Hello, world" to a current page?

Comment: Do you mean that after submitting the form, the browser is still on the original URL? Then the servlet should be mapped to the same URL as the JSP is, and the `doGet()` of the servlet just forwards to the jsp.

Comment: but how can i map it? if i change /hello on index.jsp it doesn't work

Comment: The mapping of URLs to servlet classes is controlled in web.xml.